# To find LI Solutions of Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The maximum number of linearly independent solution of differential equation $ \frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}} = 0 $  satisfying conditions $y(0) =1 $ are

Attempt : There are 4 linearly independent solutions $1, x, x^{2}, x^{3} $ out of which only 1 satisfies  given conditions .But textbook states answer is 4 .Can anyone explain.Thanks

Comment: How $y(t) \equiv 1$ satisfies $y(0)=0$ ?

Comment: Typo .edited  question.thanks

Comment: @Evgeny The space of solutions to the I.C. $y(0) = 1$ is a $3$-dimensional affine subspace of the $4$-dimensional space $\mathbb{V}$ of all solutions but doesn't pass contain the origin, so it spans all of $\mathbb{V}$, and hence it contains four linearly independent solutions as desired.

Comment: @Travis Yeah, after your answer I've understood where I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is linear and homogeneous, so linear combinations of solutions are solutions, and the solutions form a vector space $\mathbb{V}$. Since the equation has order $4$, this vector space has dimension $4$, and so is spanned by the identified linearly independent set $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$, that is, the general solution is
$$y(x) = a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3.$$

Which of these solutions satisfy the initial condition $y(0) = 1$?

> Substituting $y(0) = 1$ in the above general solution gives $a = 1$. So, the space of solutions is an affine hyperplane and thus spans all of $\mathbb{V}$, that is, there are four linearly independent solutions. Alternatively, one can simply write down four solutions with $a = 1$ that are linearly independent.

Comment: But $x^{3} +1 , x^{2} +1 ,x+1 ,1 $ can also be solutions so is

Comment: I have not understood how answer is 4

Comment: You've just given four linearly independent solutions, no?

Comment: Is it safe to say, that just like 4th order had four linearly independent solutions, so a nth order linear differential equation will have n linearly independent solutions?

Comment: That's true for linear, homogeneous systems without an initial condition. But the number of linearly independent solutions to such an equation *with* an initial condition depends on the initial condition. For example, given the same equation as above, $y^{(4)} = 0$, there is only a *$3$-dimensional* space of solutions that satisfies, e.g., $y(0) = 0$. Geometrically, this is because the solution space is a $3$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{V}$, i.e., it contains the origin of $\mathbb{V}$.